# How to combine the fraction over the common denominator?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, factorial

How to combine the fractions on the righthand side over the common denominator:

$$\frac{(n+1)!n!}{k!(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}=\frac{(n+k)n!(n-1)!}{k!(k-1)!(n-k)!}+\frac{n!(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(k-2)!(n-k+1)!}$$

Comment: I tried with $k!(k-1)!(n-k+1)$ but I don't know how to do it with factorial

Comment: This seems to be related to your question about [Lah numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number): [Showing that the Lah numbers satisfy $L(n + 1, k) = (n + k)L(n, k) + L(n, k - 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/356220)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
\color{red}{k!}\cdot \color{blue}{(k-1)!}\cdot \color{green}{(n-k)!} &= \color{red}{k(k-1)!}\cdot\color{blue}{(k-1)(k-2)!}\cdot\color{green}{\dfrac{(n-k+1)!}{n-k+1}}\\
&= \dfrac{\color{red}{k}\color{blue}{(k-1)}}{\color{green}{n-k+1}} \color{red}{(k-1)!}\color{blue}{(k-2)!}\color{green}{(n-k+1)!}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$k!=k\cdot(k-1)!\\(k-1)!=(k-1)\cdot(k-2)!\\(n-k+1)!=(n-k+1)\cdot(n-k)!$$